# Android MediaMuxer Audio Issue

Tags: android, audio, video, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I am trying to use MediaMuxer to add a audio track to a video. The following code works but the audio stops halfway through the video. Both the video and audio files only have one track.  The playback speed of the audio and video seem to be fine. The audio file is longer than the video so I dont think that is the issue. I have been at this for a while now can cant figure it out.

```
private void createFinalVideo(){

    String outputFile = "";

     try {

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "final.mp4");
        file.createNewFile();
        outputFile = file.getAbsolutePath();

        MediaExtractor videoExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
        videoExtractor.setDataSource(OUTPUT);

        MediaExtractor audioExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
        final AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getAssets().openFd("audio.m4a");
        audioExtractor.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());

        Log.d(TAG, "Video Extractor Track Count " + videoExtractor.getTrackCount() );
        Log.d(TAG, "Audio Extractor Track Count " + audioExtractor.getTrackCount() );

        MediaMuxer muxer = new MediaMuxer(outputFile, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);

        videoExtractor.selectTrack(0);
        MediaFormat videoFormat = videoExtractor.getTrackFormat(0);
        int videoTrack = muxer.addTrack(videoFormat);

        audioExtractor.selectTrack(0);
        MediaFormat audioFormat = audioExtractor.getTrackFormat(0);
        int audioTrack = muxer.addTrack(audioFormat);

        Log.d(TAG, "Video Format " + videoFormat.toString() );
        Log.d(TAG, "Audio Format " + audioFormat.toString() );

        boolean sawEOS = false;
        int frameCount = 0;
        int offset = 100;
        int sampleSize = 256 * 1024;
        ByteBuffer videoBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(sampleSize);
        ByteBuffer audioBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(sampleSize);
        BufferInfo videoBufferInfo = new BufferInfo();
        BufferInfo audioBufferInfo = new BufferInfo();

        videoExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
        audioExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);

        muxer.start();

        while (!sawEOS) 
        {
            videoBufferInfo.offset = offset;
            audioBufferInfo.offset = offset;

            videoBufferInfo.size = videoExtractor.readSampleData(videoBuf, offset);
            audioBufferInfo.size = audioExtractor.readSampleData(audioBuf, offset);

            if (videoBufferInfo.size < 0 || audioBufferInfo.size < 0) 
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "saw input EOS.");
                sawEOS = true;
                videoBufferInfo.size = 0;
                audioBufferInfo.size = 0;
            } 
            else 
            {
                videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = videoExtractor.getSampleTime();
                videoBufferInfo.flags = videoExtractor.getSampleFlags();
                muxer.writeSampleData(videoTrack, videoBuf, videoBufferInfo);
                videoExtractor.advance();

                audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = audioExtractor.getSampleTime();
                audioBufferInfo.flags = audioExtractor.getSampleFlags();
                muxer.writeSampleData(audioTrack, audioBuf, audioBufferInfo);
                audioExtractor.advance();

                frameCount++;

                Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Video PresentationTimeUs:" + videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs +" Flags:" + videoBufferInfo.flags +" Size(KB) " + videoBufferInfo.size / 1024);
                Log.d(TAG, "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Audio PresentationTimeUs:" + audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs +" Flags:" + audioBufferInfo.flags +" Size(KB) " + audioBufferInfo.size / 1024);

            }
        }
        muxer.stop();
        muxer.release();


     } catch (IOException e) {
         Log.d(TAG, "Mixer Error 1 " + e.getMessage());
     } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.d(TAG, "Mixer Error 2 " + e.getMessage());
     }

    return;
}
```

The media format print out is the following

```
Video Format {max-input-size=1572864, frame-rate=28, height=1920, csd-0=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=18,capacity=18], width=1072, durationUs=2968688, csd-1=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=8,capacity=8], mime=video/avc, isDMCMMExtractor=1}

Audio Format {max-input-size=1572864, encoder-padding=708, aac-profile=2, csd-0=java.nio.ByteArrayBuffer[position=0,limit=2,capacity=2], sample-rate=44100, durationUs=19783401, channel-count=2, encoder-delay=2112, mime=audio/mp4a-latm, isDMCMMExtractor=1}
```

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is it *exactly* halfway?  I'm just wondering if there's an error in a calculation somewhere, and you're not actually feeding in all the data you expect.

Comment: The video is 15 seconds long and the audio seems to stop consistently at 9 seconds. If the video is 10 seconds long the audio stops at 6 seconds. Should i share the frame log.

Comment: The issue was the video extractor was pulling data out quicker than the audio extractor. Splitting the audio and video into separate loops fixed the issue.

Comment: @user346443 could you please post your answer.
Facing same issue here.

Comment: @user346443 i think the problem is frame length for a video frame (1/28s = roughly 36ms) is not the same as an aac frame (1024/44100 = 23ms), so for the same frame count video frames is longer in duration than your audio. so audio stops at 23/36 or roughly 9/15 or 6/10 of the video length

Answer (score 0):

user346443: The issue was the video extractor was pulling data out quicker than the audio extractor. Splitting the audio and video into separate loops fixed the issue.